# add send to messenger button in email

Tags: email, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, bots, facebook-messenger

I am making a feedback system using a facebook messenger bot. When the order is completed, then a email will be send to the user for feedback. I wanted to add "send to messenger" button in the email so that after clicking that button, a auto generated message will be send to the user's messenger for asking the feedback.

I have completed all the steps but I am not able to send the button in mail. The button does not show in the mail. The bot is still not published yet.

So how can I make the button to show?

Here is my index.html page:

```html
<div>
  <div class="fb-send-to-messenger" 
    messenger_app_id='1133966933290445'
    page_id='944059262358972'
    data-ref="123556" 
    color="blue" 
    size="standard">
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <p>The "Message Us" plugin takes the user directly to Messenger and into a thread with your Page.</p>

  <div class="fb-messengermessageus" 
    messenger_app_id='1133966933290445'
    page_id='944059262358972'
    color="blue"
    size="standard">
  </div>
</div>
```

I am copying the view from the browser to email. I am not using node mailer now. Is it possible to work this way if the app is still under development?

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help)it will be useful to raise your content quality up

Comment: We need code please.

Comment: @j0k Did you understand this question?

Comment: @abhishekgupta yup but I don't know the answer :)